# How can I submit a form using ajax when using jQuery-Validation-Unobtrusive

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-core-3.0

I have an app that is written on the top of ASP.NET Core 3. My project use [jQuery-Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) and [jQuery-Validation-Unobtrusive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to create client-side validation.

When the user hits the submit button, currently the form gets validated and submitted using standard web request. How can I submit the form using AJAX so the page does not refresh?

The ajax submission must happen after the form is validated using [jQuery.Validation-Unobtrusive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1). How can I submit the form using AJAX instead of a standard browser call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to validations, there is something called - jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax Helpers. You need to integrate these script files as part of your page. And modify the Form element with `data-` attributes. It will start working as an Ajax form instead of a normal one. Here is a helpful article - [jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax Helpers in ASP.NET Core](https://dotnetthoughts.net/jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-helpers-in-aspnet-core/)